# GDB with ECLIPSE GUI over remote server?

Tags: eclipse, gdb, eclipse-cdt, gdbserver, eclipse-rse

I would love to debug my software with ECLIPSE as front end to GDB. Our build set up as follows.

- Linux server with code base
- Windows accessing code base via Samba (Eclipse IDE)
- Software is built on Linux server with makefiles (No ECLIPSE control
  here, its more of an editor for now)
- NFS mount to target (it's embedded SW)
- remote debugging using command line GDB

I do not have an option to change my build environment, its too much of effort, moreover Cygwin is too slow compared to Linux.

The only way I can access the server is with ssh. The server has only basic X-Window manager, so VNC is not an option.

Is there any way I can make use of ECLIPSE as an IDE rather than as editor ? I am mainly interested in utilizing its remote DEBUGGING feature.

---

EDIT

ERROR establishing communication

TARGET

```
#./mipsel-linux-gdbserver-7.1 :1234 hello
```

HOST

```
$ gdb hello
(gdb) target remote 10.201.122.177:1234
Remote debugging using 10.201.122.177:1234
warning: while parsing target description (at line 10): Target description speci
fied unknown architecture "mips"
warning: Could not load XML target description; ignoring
Reply contains invalid hex digit 59
```

I also did try recompiling a gdb server from cygwin sources for my target, but the results were no different. My target architecture is MIPS.

---

POSSIBLE ANOTHER APPROACH

Is [RSE](http://www.eclipse.org/tm/tutorial/index.php) (Remote System Explorer) alternate to what I am trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 5):

> Target description specified unknown architecture "mips"

Your target is (obviously) mipsel-linux.

Your GDB is (most likely) native linux-i386 or linux-x86_64. You can see how your GDB was configured with

```
(gdb) show version
...
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux".
```

In order to debug mipsel-linux target, you need to build a cross-gdb (`--host=x86_64-linux --target=mipsel-linux` or some such) and then get Eclipse to invoke that GDB instead of the native one.

Comment: Details on how to build the cross-gdb are here: https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingCrossGDBandGDBserver

Answer (score 0):

Use ssh server on remote linux system e.g. dropbear. and then you can use eclipse as frontend for remove debugging over ssh.

Comment: Could you clarify more your solution?

Answer (score -1):

You can debug from Eclipse on Windows over gdbserver running on embedded SW. I guess Eclipse  should load debugging symbols via Samba and there should be no problem.

Comment: I doubt hat, the debug symbols will have the wrong path info. like I build from my home directory, the path info of a source file will be /home/user/src/source.c, but on a Windows PC, it will be some mapped network drive, so path will be m:/src/source.c

Comment: gdb has some support of path substitution [set substitute-path from to](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html), try it.

Comment: Ok now I tried to do command line debugging in cygwin. I find GDB version to be 7.3.50.20110821-cvs. I am unable to get the communication established with target. Updated error messaged as edit.